# Is that possible to write to a word file from a C language function?

Tags: c, ms-word

I have a Library management system written in C language which has I/O file in `.dat`. How is it possible to get output of word file from this function:

```
void viewbooks(void)  //show the list of book persists in library
{
    int i=0,j;
    system("cls");
    gotoxy(1,1);
    printf("*********************************Book List*****************************");
    gotoxy(2,2);
    printf(" CATEGORY     ID    BOOK NAME     AUTHOR       QTY     PRICE     RackNo ");
    j=4;
    fp=fopen("Bibek.dat","rb"); //the .dat file getting data to be showed
    while(fread(&a,sizeof(a),1,fp)==1) // .dat file to be read
    {
        gotoxy(3,j);
        printf("%s",a.cat);
        gotoxy(16,j);
        printf("%d",a.id);
        gotoxy(22,j);
        printf("%s",a.name);
        gotoxy(36,j);
        printf("%s",a.Author);
        gotoxy(50,j);
        printf("%d",a.quantity);
        gotoxy(57,j);
        printf("%.2f",a.Price);
        gotoxy(69,j);
        printf("%d",a.rackno);
        printf("\n\n");
        j++;
        i=i+a.quantity;
    }
    gotoxy(3,25);
    printf("Total Books =%d",i);
    fclose(fp);
    gotoxy(35,25);
    returnfunc();
}
```

Comment: from *this* function? well, not at all. But of course you can write word files, get hold of the OOXML specification and do your output accordingly (hint: this is a **massive** amount of work and your "function" will increase to probably several modules)

Comment: What is `a` and why do you expect every data element to be the same exact size (including a terminating zero)? What has this to do with writing a Word file?

Comment: @Felix Palmen would u give me some links to be followed?

Comment: @moh89 just google for OOXML. I can give you another hint: You WILL want to use some external libraries **at least** for handling XML and the CAB archive format (you need both for a valid OOXML file). And, no offense, but looking at this example code, you don't want to attempt something like this now. (Later you will probably realize it just isn't worth the effort)

Comment: What do you mean by "a Word file"? The type .rtf or .doc or .docx? If you are (?) using Turbo C I suspect you won't be interested .docx ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane that's a nice hint as well, but only complicates matters ;) I was naturally thinking of the *most recent* file format

Comment: @WeatherVane a is the object of books class which i m using attributes to be called

Comment: @moh89 I once wrote some `C#` code for work that could automatically *manipulate* an OOXML Infopath document -- this was already a huge mess and several weeks worth of development work. Just don't do it ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen tnx ! its nice guide,i will try it!

Comment: @FelixPalmen so what is ur easiest solution u suggest?

Comment: @moh89 when I have (before .docx) needed to create Word documents from a C program I have created a .rtf file, where the format is much simpler than .doc. I then load it into Word and re-save in the required format.

Comment: @moh89 just forget about writing word files yourself. Maybe write some markdown format and convert e.g. with [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/)

Comment: @WeatherVane i will try it!

Comment: From the look of the data example would Excel be more appropriate? You can work with .csv files very easily.

Comment: @WeatherVane the issue is giving customer more comfort by giving ready .doc file

Comment: @FelixPalmen i might get result to upload here

Comment: If you really want to write rich text which can loaded and processed in (Win?)Word, why don't you use [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)? For the creation of HTML files, you don't need anymore than what you already used (in your sample code). (There are some examples on the linked Wikipedia article.) Though, you might set the encoding of the document to UTF-8, you don't need anything else than ASCII characters (i.e. any non-ASCII character may be written as entity e.g. `"&#252;"` for "ü"). Btw. your web browser would be able to display your output file also...

Comment: @Scheff then then i need [link] (https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) to show up my interface in html which is much more complex to me!

Comment: Either I didn't understand what you actually want to do or you didn't understand me. Please, see my answer. I wrote a formatted table in HTML using nothing else than the C standard library. (Only `stdio.h` had to be included...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML is one possibility to describe rich-text. Being the file format of WWW, it is well-established. IMHO, probably any modern Rich-Text text processing tool does support it. (I personally know this for WinWord – for years.)

To write an HTML file is rather easy as the HTML file is actually nothing else than source code which may be written in plain ASCII.

A short demonstration `print-HTML.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Entry {
  const char *author;
  const char *title;
};

void printEntry(FILE *f, struct Entry *pEntry, int i)
{
  fprintf(f,
    "<tr><!-- start of table row -->\n"
    "<td>%d</td><!-- number -->\n"
    "<td>%s</td><!-- Author -->\n"
    "<td>%s</td><!-- Title -->\n"
    "</tr><!-- end of table row -->\n",
    i, pEntry->author, pEntry->title);
}

void printTable(FILE *f, size_t nEntries, struct Entry table[])
{
  fprintf(f,
    "<table><!-- start of table -->\n"
    "<tr><!-- start of table head row -->\n"
    "<th>No.</th><th>Author</th><th>Title</th>\n"
    "</tr><!-- end of table head row -->\n");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nEntries; ++i) {
    printEntry(f, table + i, (int)i + 1);
  }
  fprintf(f,
    "</table><!-- end of table -->\n");
}

void printDoc(
  FILE *f, const char *title, size_t nEntries, struct Entry table[])
{
  fprintf(f,
    "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
    "<html>\n"
    "<head>\n"
    "<title>%s</title>\n"
    "</head>\n"
    "<body>\n"
    "<h1>%s</h1>\n",
    title, title);
  printTable(f, nEntries, table);
  fprintf(f,
    "</body>\n"
    "</html>\n");
}

int main()
{
  /* the sample table */
  struct Entry table[] = {
    { "Kernighan and Ritchie", "The C Programming Language" },
    { "Kernighan and Ritchie", "Programming in C" },
    { "Tim Berners-Lee", "Weaving the Web" },
    { "Tim Berners-Lee", "Hypertext Markup Language: the HTML explained from the Inventor of the WWW" }
  };
  enum { nEntries = sizeof table / sizeof table[0] };
  /* output as HTML */
  printDoc(stdout, "My Favorite Books", nEntries, table);
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

Sample session:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -o print-HTML print-HTML.c

$ ./print-HTML 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Favorite Books</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Favorite Books</h1>
<table><!-- start of table -->
<tr><!-- start of table head row -->
<th>No.</th><th>Author</th><th>Title</th>
</tr><!-- end of table head row -->
<tr><!-- start of table row -->
<td>1</td><!-- number -->
<td>Kernighan and Ritchie</td><!-- Author -->
<td>The C Programming Language</td><!-- Title -->
</tr><!-- end of table row -->
<tr><!-- start of table row -->
<td>2</td><!-- number -->
<td>Kernighan and Ritchie</td><!-- Author -->
<td>Programming in C</td><!-- Title -->
</tr><!-- end of table row -->
<tr><!-- start of table row -->
<td>3</td><!-- number -->
<td>Tim Berners-Lee</td><!-- Author -->
<td>Weaving the Web</td><!-- Title -->
</tr><!-- end of table row -->
<tr><!-- start of table row -->
<td>4</td><!-- number -->
<td>Tim Berners-Lee</td><!-- Author -->
<td>Hypertext Markup Language: the HTML explained from the Inventor of the WWW</td><!-- Title -->
</tr><!-- end of table row -->
</table><!-- end of table -->
</body>
</html>

$ ./print-HTML >test.html

$
```

Below, some snapshots of the applications I opened `test.html` in:

Firefox:

[image: Snapshot of <code>test.html</code> in Firefox]

MS Word for Windows:

[image: Snapshot of <code>test.html</code> in MS Word for Windows]

MS Excel:

[image: Snapshot of <code>test.html</code> in MS Excel]

**Update:**

In the above sample code, I carefully prevented to use meta-characters (`<`, `>`, `&`, and `"`) in the text pieces. If these characters appear in the original texts they may not be printed as is (as these characters may have special meaning in the HTML syntax). Instead, they have to be replaced by their entities:

- `<` ⇒ `&lt;` (begin of tag)
- `>` ⇒ `&gt;` (end of tag)
- `&` ⇒ `&amp;` (begin of entity)
- `"` ⇒ `&quot;` (begin/end of quoted attribute values)
- `'` ⇒ `&apos;` (alternative begin/end of quoted attribute values).

In HTML, there are a lot more pre-defined entities. (In XML, these are the only pre-defined entities.)

The updated sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printHTMLText(FILE *f, const char *text)
{
  for (; *text; ++text) {
    switch (*text) {
      case '<': fprintf(f, "&lt;"); break;
      case '>': fprintf(f, "&gt;"); break;
      case '&': fprintf(f, "&amp;"); break;
      case '"': fprintf(f, "&quot;"); break;
      case '\'': fprintf(f, "&apos;"); break;
      default: putc(*text, f);
    }
  }
}

struct Entry {
  const char *author;
  const char *title;
};

void printEntry(FILE *f, struct Entry *pEntry, int i)
{
  fprintf(f,
    "<tr><!-- start of table row -->\n"
    "<td>%d</td><!-- number -->\n"
    "<td>",
    i);
  printHTMLText(f, pEntry->author);
  fprintf(f,
    "</td><!-- Author -->\n"
    "<td>");
  printHTMLText(f, pEntry->title);
  fprintf(f,
    "</td><!-- Title -->\n"
    "</tr><!-- end of table row -->\n");
}

void printTable(FILE *f, size_t nEntries, struct Entry table[])
{
  fprintf(f,
    "<table><!-- start of table -->\n"
    "<tr><!-- start of table head row -->\n"
    "<th>No.</th><th>Author</th><th>Title</th>\n"
    "</tr><!-- end of table head row -->\n");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nEntries; ++i) {
    printEntry(f, table + i, (int)i + 1);
  }
  fprintf(f,
    "</table><!-- end of table -->\n");
}

void printDoc(
  FILE *f, const char *title, size_t nEntries, struct Entry table[])
{
  fprintf(f,
    "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
    "<html>\n"
    "<head>\n"
    "<title>");
  printHTMLText(f, title);
  fprintf(f,
    "</title>\n"
    "</head>\n"
    "<body>\n"
    "<h1>");
  printHTMLText(f, title);
  fprintf(f,
    "</h1>\n");
  printTable(f, nEntries, table);
  fprintf(f,
    "</body>\n"
    "</html>\n");
}

int main()
{
  struct Entry table[] = {
    { "Kernighan & Ritchie", "The C Programming Language" },
    { "Kernighan & Ritchie", "Programming in C" },
    { "Tim Berners-Lee", "Weaving the Web" },
    { "Tim Berners-Lee", "Hypertext Markup Language: the HTML explained from the Inventor of the WWW" }
  };
  enum { nEntries = sizeof table / sizeof table[0] };
  printDoc(stdout, "My Favorite Books", nEntries, table);
  return 0;
}
```

will print e.g.

```
{ "Kernighan & Ritchie", "The C Programming Language" }
```

as:

```
<td>Kernighan &amp; Ritchie</td><!-- Author -->
<td>The C Programming Language</td><!-- Title -->
```

Note:

`"` has actually to be replaced in double-quoted attribute values only. (as well as `'` in single-quoted attribute values). In turn, `<` and `>` need not to be replaced in attribute values. To keep things simple and compact, the function `printHTMLText()` replaces any of these characters.

Comment: that could help for formatting the .dat file to any other useful format to be read,but the issue is u had define constant variables! my variables are all object of classes,then how to convert them ?!

Comment: thumbs up for going the extra mile.

Comment: @moh89 I defined constant variables to make the sample compact. In your sample code, you just provided the code to read data from a .dat file and to print them formatted. In your sample code, you read `a` with `fread()` but the declaration of `a` (probably a `struct`) is missing. Therefore, I declared `struct Entry` - just to demonstrate the concept. I assumed you will be able to apply it to your project appropriately.

Comment: @Scheff tnx got it!

Comment: About HTML syntax, there are many tutorials. IMHO, if somebody is able to master C he should be able to understand HTML as well. The most difficult topic is IMHO the [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) - namely of the input data. For HTML itself, I would always prefer [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as it is international, available on all relevant platforms, and well supported.

Comment: I just made an update as I didn't consider `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, `'` in my first version of sample code, and I felt bad about this afterwards...