# Is it possible to manipulate information on another program's Text file with a custom made GUI? If so, how?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I was wondering if it is possible to manipulate information on another program's Text file with a custom-made GUI. I am trying to accomplish this by using Glade3 and GTK+ in C++. I am flexible to work in another language, but I am trying to work in C++ for now.
Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by "another program's Text file"? Also, even if you clarify that you will find these kind of questions are not well received here. A better question would be: I have tried X and I have a specific problem here"

Comment: _another program's Text file_ If the other program is a plain-text editor that's very easy. (All modern GUI libraries I know provide a basic text editor widget with more or less basic features built in.) If the other program is a rich-text editor (like e.g. MS Word) then... I would go with a trick -- to use an exchange format which is quite easy to handle in another appl. as well like e.g. here: [Is that possible to write to a word file from a C language function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44614364/7478597)

Comment: another program's text file in just a plain-text editor.  Yeah, I figured that was the case bolov, but I wanted to see if it was possible at all before investing time into a project that may not produce meaningful results. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: The program that I want to manipulate utilizes just a plain ol' text editor.  Scheff. Its good to know that modern GUI libraries have those abilties. Thank you.